Segmentation label/ masks for GIS data
I'm trying to create segmentation labels/masks using a terrain GIS dataset to locate some objects (like trees).
For the labels of trees, do I need to convert the geographical coordinates to pixel coordinates to create my mask which I can do using the transform present in the geotiff file of terrain data?
If yes, will this affect the model getting trained as the model will be dependent on the transform matrix of the terrain dataset?

When you use e.g. rasterio.rasterize, this is dealt by the rasterize function. You only need to pass the transform to the function.
Something like this:
mask = features.rasterize(
    ((g, 255) for g, v in trees),
    out_shape=terrain_img.shape,
    transform=terrain_img.transform,
)


Thanks @Pieter for your reply. What do you think about the second question for modelling.

For segmentation I suppose you mean training e.g. a deep neural network or something like that to segment the images? Typically this doesn't take in account coordinates at all. It only learns to recognize patterns in the pixel values. If this is what you are looking for, you can check out orthoseg
